# Toroidal frame system

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

*Context:
I'm following the textbook of Barrett O'Neill about differential geometry. In order to calculate the connection forms of the torous I need the relation between a toroidal frame and the natural frame. *

I'm trying to construct a toridal frame system in terms of the natural frame system $\{\hat{e}_x,\,\hat{e}_y,\,\hat{e}_z\}$, where $\hat{e}_x=(1,\,0,\,0)$, etc. The same as with an spherical frame $\{\hat{e}_r,\,\hat{e}_\theta,\,\hat{e}_\phi\}$, where:

$\hat{e}_r=\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\hat{e}_x+\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)\hat{e}_y+\sin(\phi)\hat{e}_z$

$\hat{e}_\theta=-\sin(\theta)\hat{e}_x+\cos(\theta)\hat{e}_y$

$\hat{e}_\phi=-\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\hat{e}_x-\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\hat{e}_y+\cos(\phi)\hat{e}_z$

My attempt was to construct parametric curves, then take its derivative to make a tangent vector and finally make it a unit vector (this seems to work fine por cylindrical and spherical frames). For example, i'll take the next curve on the tourus with its standar coordinates

$\alpha(\phi)=((R+\rho_o\,\cos(\phi))\,\cos(\theta_o),\,(R+\rho_o\,\cos(\phi))\,\sin(\theta_o),\,\rho_o\,\\\sin(\phi))$

where $R$, $\rho_o$ and $\theta_o$ are fixed (i'll just take a point on the torous with its standar coordinates and fix two of them). Then:

$\alpha'(\phi)=(-\rho_o\,\sin(\phi)\,\cos(\theta_o),\,-\rho_o\,\sin(\phi)\,\sin(\theta_o),\,\rho_o\,\cos(\phi))$

where it's easy to see that $|\alpha'(\phi)|=\rho_o$. Finally:
 $\hat{e}_\phi=-\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\hat{e}_x-\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\hat{e}_y+\cos(\phi)\hat{e}_z$ 
wich is the same as in spherical frame and this happens with the rest. So, I came to this: Toroidal frame is same as spherical frame...And this jus't feels wrong.

So, I would love and I will appreciate some help here

Comment: How does this happen with the rest? And I'm not sure why you're doing this to find the connection form of the torus. I don't remember precisely what O'Neil does, but don't you have the metric in terms of $\phi$ and $\theta$? This gives you an orthonormal coframe, and then the structure equations are immediately in play.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I understand my mistake. They are actually share the same expresión and because of that have the same connection forms $\omega_{ij}$. The only thing that changes is how they act wit respect functions; i.e. While $\hat{e}_\theta[f]={1\over r\cos(\phi)}{\partial f\over\partial\theta}$ in a espherical frame, in a toroidal frame will be $\hat{e}_\theta[f]={1\over R+\rho\cos(\phi)}{\partial f\over\partial\theta}$